# Number 1 to Z input using def operator

Tags: python, ascii, slice, python-3.4, function

I'm having trouble with this question, and I don't know where to start:

Write a function that prints characters using the following header:

```
def printChars(ch1, ch2, numberPerLine):
```

This function prints the characters between ch1 and ch2 with the specified numbers per line. Write a test program that prints ten characters per line from 1 to Z.

I have this so far:

`import string`

```
import random

ch1 = 1
ch2 = str('chr(90)')
char_line = 10
numberoflines = 36
def printChars(ch1,ch2,char_line):
    for i in range(numberoflines):
        i = 0
    while i in range(numberoflines):
        i += 0
        print(string.digits)
        print(string.ascii_uppercase)
    if i <= char_line:
        print('\n')
    elif i >=36:
        return

printChars(ch1,ch2,char_line)
```

and when this is inputted, I just get a repetition of

```
0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

When I should be getting

```
1234567890
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZ
```

P.S. I'm a newcomer to StackOverflow, and I'm still learning the system

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating things - you just need to iterate from `ch1` to `ch2` and keep track of how many characters you had so for in the current line - if it's `numberPerLine`, print a linebreak:

```
def printChars(ch1, ch2, numberPerLine):
    for i in range(ord(ch1), ord(ch2) + 1):
        print(chr(i), end='')
        if (i - ord(ch1)) % numberPerLine == numberPerLine - 1:
            print()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly but when i inputted it into the code I got a typeError: TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel you are passing `1` instead of the string representation `"1"`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand too well, could you possibly tell me what I need to remove and/or add? thanks

Comment: You are calling it with an int literal, `1` - `printChars(1, 'z', 10)`. You should be calling it with a string containing the character `'1'`: `printChars('1', 'z', 10)`.

Comment: Now when i replace the 1 as a string im getting extra variables such as :; <=> and no zero